# Android - Collapsible LinearLayout with multiple items

Tags: android, android-layout, visibility, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make a list of `LinearLayout` become `VISIBLE` at a click on a "header" `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/sample_title" ...>
    <TextView ... />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sample_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Sample text 1"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Sample text 2"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Programmatically:

```
mSampleTitle = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.sample_title);
mSampleTitle.setOnClickListener(this);
mSampleContent = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.sample_content);

[...]

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == mSampleTitle) {
        mSampleContent.setVisibility(mSampleContent.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

It works fine when there is only one `TextView` to show, but as soon as there is more, only the first one becomes visible and all the rest is just blank space.

Thank you

Comment: Are all your textviews declared as "fill_parent"?

Comment: I edited the OP with the complete XML.

Comment: Looks like I forgot a `android:orientation="vertical"`...

Comment: Ah that was my second choice. Maybe should have been the first one ;)

Comment: I still find it strange that the exact space that those items would have taken is left empty at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, stupid error.

I forgot the `android:orientation="vertical"`. The code changing the VISIBILITY works fine.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sample_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sample_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >
```

I still find weird the fact that they were so much blank space below that LinearLayout horizontal...